# Grant privileges for new schemas on postgres

Tags: postgresql, schema, privileges

I have a Postgres 9.6.11. When a new schema is creating I want to grant privileges for the role name "select_role" with privileges "using".
My first thing was using the default privileges, but a schema hasn't default privileges.
The second thing was using triggers but I cannot use this for the system catalog.

Can anyone have an idea of how to do this? I don't have too much experience with Postgres.
If someone can help me with writing this I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can set default privileges on schemas:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE laurenz GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS TO select_role;
```

Now whenever user `laurenz` creates a schema, `select_role` will be granted `USAGE` on that schema.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
I was running this a few hours ago

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE select_user GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS TO select_role ;
```

and the results I got this error.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SCHEMAS"

> LINE 1: ...LT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE select_user GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS TO...

I don't know how to resolve this.